# Bower Not Found

Tags: terminal, zurb-foundation, bower, bower-install

I have seen this question asked 10000 times, but none of the answers seems to fit my situation.

When I try to run a command that requires bower like:

```
foundation new projet
```

It says:

```
Can't find bower. You can install it by running: sudo npm install -g bower
```

So I ran this:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Everything goes fine.
But when I run the foundation code again, it says that I don't have bower.

If I run:

```
bower -v
```

It says:

```
-bash: bower: command not found
```

I have checked my .bash_profile and did the:

```
export PATH=~/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

It didn't work.

I don't know what's going on.

I also tried fixing the disk permission with disk utility.

I'm on a mac.

Comment: What do you get with `npm bin`? Are you sure that `~/usr/local/share/npm/bin` is the correct path to your npm bin? You can try `export PATH="$(npm bin):$PATH"` also.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work. I'll post my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.
What I did was delete all the npm and node folders located on the $Home folder, and reinstalled it.
Everything works fine now.